# ServiceTestRule#startService timeout for unbound services

Tags: java, android, android-testing, android-junit

I am being faced with [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214359) issue, basically the ServiceTestRule throws a TimeoutException when startService is called in an unbound services, and would like to know if someone knows of a possible workaround until a fix is released?

The unbound service class:

```
public class UnboundService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class UnboundServiceTest {
    @Rule
    public final ServiceTestRule serviceRule = new ServiceTestRule();

    @Test
    public void worksAsStartedService() throws TimeoutException {
        Intent intent = new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext(), UnboundService.class);
        serviceRule.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    @Rule
public final ServiceTestRule mServiceRule = ServiceTestRule.withTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: The problem is not related to the timed out but that the implementation of `startService` is trying to "bind to the started service to guarantee its started and connected before test execution". Check the way `ServiceTestRule` was implemented. They call `bindServiceAndWait`, but as it is an unbound service it never binds.